# is pushforward of a kähler class under a finite map kähler?

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

If $f: X \to Y$ is a finite map of compact complex manifolds, then we can push a cohomology class in $H^2(X)$ by considering the dual homology class in $H_{n-2}(X)$, pushing it forward, and then considering the dual of the push-forward in $H^2(Y)$. The question is: if class $a \in H^2(X)$ contains a kähler form, is it true that $f_* a$ also does? The answer is clearly positive when the map $f$ is unramified, in which case the kähler representative of $f_* a$ is just the "summing over the fibres" form, but what if the map is ramified?

passing to currents, it would be possible to construct a positive current on $Y$ as the push-forward of the kähler form on $X$, but I am not sure how to smooth it.

Comment: "Yes" by Demailly and Paun's characterization of the Kahler cone as the set of cohomology classes $\omega$ such that $\int_Y \omega^p > 0$ for every subspace $Y$ of dimension $p$ and the fact that finite maps act very simply on cohomology. There must be simpler way there though.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon  indeed, but I was thinking that there maybe is some regularization argument. I was also thinking about the same question for a blowdown map

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon actually, I don't think I know why a push-forward of a kähler current under a properm should be a kähler current, though it must be true or the characterization of Fujiki class C via existence of a kähler current wouldn't work. while we are at it, perhaps you could tell me where I could read about to educate myself? would much appreciate it!

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon I am mainly confused why the pushforward would be bounded below by a hermitian form

Answer (score 2):

This is getting a bit long for a comment, so forgive me an answer.

To answer your original question (in a different way than you really wanted, I gather), the pushforward of a Kahler class $\omega$ by a finite map $f : X \to Y$ of compact manifolds is again a Kahler class. If $Z \subset Y$ is a closed analytic subspace of dimension $p$ then
$$
\int_Z f_* \omega^p = \operatorname{deg} f_{|f^{-1}(Z)} \int_{f^{-1}(Z)} \omega^p > 0
$$
because $f^{-1}(Z)$ is again a closed analytic subspace of dimension $p$ and $\omega$ is Kahler. By Demailly-Paun's characterization of the Kahler cone, it follows that $f_*\omega$ is Kahler.

You asked for references on Kahler currents, and I gather that what you actually wanted to do was to prove the above directly (which should be doable, we're totally nuking a mosquito). The ones I know for Kahler currents in complex geometry are Demailly's [book](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf) (Chapters 1 and 3) and [notes](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/analmeth.pdf) (later chapters; it's advanced applications of everything in the book).

Specifically, Demailly discusses direct images of currents in Chapter 1.2 and positive currents in Chapter 3, and states without proof (but with pointers on how to assemble a proof) that direct images of a positive current by a proper map (which a finite map between compact manifolds surely is) is again a positive current of the same degree in Proposition 1.17 in Chapter 3. He also discusses smoothing of currents, but I don't have exact references to the parts that would be interesting to you.

Comment: thank you! I have read the bit about positive currents in Demailly's book, but what I am still confused about is the following. A Kähler current $T$ is not just a positive current, it is a positive current such that $T - \psi$ is positive where $\psi$ is a positive (not necessarily closed) $(1,1)$-form. How is this property preserved by the pushforward?

Comment: ..the condition is even stricter, $\psi$ is the $(1,1)$ form associated to a hermitian metric (so can't be degenerate)